# UNINITIALIZED READ at where?

Tags: c++, qt

```
internals::PointLatLng MercatorProjection::FromPixelToLatLng(const int &x, const int &y, const int &zoom)
{
    internals::PointLatLng ret;// = internals::PointLatLng.Empty;

    Size s = GetTileMatrixSizePixel(zoom);
    double mapSizeX = s.Width();
    double mapSizeY = s.Height();

    double xx = (Clip(x, 0, mapSizeX - 1) / mapSizeX) - 0.5;
    double yy = 0.5 - (Clip(y, 0, mapSizeY - 1) / mapSizeY);

    ret.SetLat(90 - 360 * atan(exp(-yy * 2 * M_PI)) / M_PI);
    ret.SetLng(360 * xx);

    return ret;
}
double MercatorProjection::Clip(const double &n, const double &minValue, const double &maxValue)  const
{
    return qMin(qMax(n, minValue), maxValue);
}
```

I have the above code and I used Dr. Memory to check my program but it always complain that there is

```
 UNINITIALIZED READ: reading 0x0037e410-0x0037e414 4 byte(s)
```

at

```
    double xx = (Clip(x, 0, mapSizeX - 1) / mapSizeX) - 0.5;
    double yy = 0.5 - (Clip(y, 0, mapSizeY - 1) / mapSizeY);
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: It's probably inside of `internals::PointLatLng` default constructor some values are not initialized, when used in `internals::PointLatLng::SetLat` at `ret.SetLat(...)`.

Comment: Well, you use `x` and `y` (which are references to int) on those lines and you haven't shown the code where you initialize the ints.

Comment: You're passing references to uninitialised variables to `FromPixelToLatLng`. There is no reason to pass `int`'s by const reference.

Comment: Why there is no reason: references are pointers, and your pointer type is probably as big if not bigger than `int`s in memory. Since the reference is `const`, the parameters can also not be edited. You get the exact same behaviour by copying the `int` without any performance loss.

Comment: but is that the reason it gives me UNINITIALIZED READ?